FlashList wrong images loaded when scrolling
I'm using FlashList to display a list of item (avatar, title). While scrolling, the wrong images of the items are shown (mixed).
According to the documentation, this happens because of the Recycling, since FlashList does not destroy the item when an item gets out of the viewport, but re-renders the component with a different item prop.
The component hierarchy returned from renderItem make use of useState (ideally component hierarchy returned from renderItem should not make use of useState for best performance).
const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }: ListRenderItemInfo<Avatar>) => (
        <ListItemAvatar
          logoUri: getLogos(item),
          id: item.name + index
        />
    ),
    []
);


type Avatar = {
  id?: string;
  logoUri?: ImageURISource | Array<ImageURISource>;
};

export const Avatar = ({ id, logoUri }: AvatarProps) => {
  const indexValue = useRef<number>(0);
  const lastItemId = useRef(id);

  const [sourceImage, setSourceImage] = useState(
    logoUri === undefined
      ? undefined
      : Array.isArray(logoUri)
      ? logoUri[0]
      : logoUri
  );

  if (id !== lastItemId.current) {
    console.log(`${lastItemId.current} has been recycled to ${id}`);

    lastItemId.current = id;
    setSourceImage(
      logoUri === undefined
        ? undefined
        : Array.isArray(logoUri)
        ? logoUri[indexValue.current]
        : logoUri
    );
  }

  const onError = () => {
    if (Array.isArray(logoUri) && indexValue.current + 1 < logoUri.length) {
      indexValue.current = indexValue.current + 1;
      setImageSource(logoUri[indexValue.current]);
      return;
    }
    setSourceImage(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {sourceImage === undefined ? (
        <Icon />
      ) : (
        <Image source={sourceImage} onError={onError}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

As you can see, I reset every state when current id does not match the lastItemId but this does not work.
How can I fix it?

react-native: 0.70
@shopify/flash-list: 1.4.3


This is a really convoluted code for displaying the Avatar.  The reason for the complexity seems to be that you try a different possible source when loading the first image fails.  If this can be removed, and you can handle broken image checking in some other way, then you no longer need any state and it becomes trivial:
export const Avatar = ({ logoUri }: AvatarProps) => {
    const sourceImage = Array.isArray(logoUri) ? logoUri[0] : logoUri;

    return (
        <View>
            {sourceImage === undefined ? (
                <Icon />
            ) : (
                <Image source={sourceImage} />
            )}
        </View>
    );
};

If you need to maintain the cycling through images, I would try to define it in a way where changing the item won't impact any state.  For example, instead of storing the index of the current position in the array, we can store the href of the failed images.  Then look through the current array for the first element that isn't a known error.  This could have performance implications if there are lots of failed images and lots of elements in the list.  But it has the benefit of resetting to the first image automatically when the item changes.

export const Avatar = ({ logoUri }: AvatarProps) => {
    // Note: using a dictionary instead of an array because it's faster to check.
    const [failedImages, setFailedImages] = useState<Record<string, true>>({});

    const sourceImage = Array.isArray(logoUri) 
        ? logoUri.find(image => image.uri && !failedImages[image.uri])
        : logoUri;

    return (
        <View>
            {sourceImage === undefined ? (
                <Icon />
            ) : (
                <Image
                    source={sourceImage}
                    onError={(error) => {
                        // Not sure if there's a way to get the src from `error` or `error.target`?  That would be better.
                        setFailedImages(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [sourceImage.uri]: true }));
                    }}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    );
};


My goal is to handle fallbacks for broken images. In case of an error, if I have one or a list ImageSourceUri, I would like to reset the state and show a fallback. I need to maintain the cycling through images.

it's an Image component that attempts to load the provided images until one is available.
If images are not available then fallback is shown.
